# Как генерировать файлы проекта Visual Studio 2008 с помощью утилиты cmake?

Tags: c, cmake, c++, visual-studio

Как генерировать файлы проекта Visual Studio 2008 с помощью утилиты cmake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для создания проект Visual Studio с помощью сmake, при имеющемся CMakeLists.txt, необходимо:

1) Если тип cmake-проекта "in sourcе" то перейти в каталог с CMakeLists.txt и набрать в командной строке

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 9 2008"
```

2) Если тип проекта "out of source" то перейти в папку, где планируется получить файлы проекта, далее набрать в командной строке

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 9 2008" путь_до_cmakelists.txt
```